# React hooks useCallback has dependency on function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I have below function

```
const handleClick = React.useCallback(
    (value) => {
      dispatch({ value });
    },
    [dispatch]
  );
```

My question is, in my case, is it necessary to have `useCallback` ? 
how React determines if the dependency is changed when the dependency is a function?

Answer (score -1):

1. It is not necessary to use `useCallback` but using that will reflect in good performance.
2. `useCallback` returns a memoized callback. According to my understanding, `react` invokes the function and only execute the callback function if there is any change in the dependencies that we have passed to it.

References:

1. [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: My question is, when `dispatch` as a dependency, how React determines if it is changed

Comment: React uses virtual DOM, whenever there is a change the change is reflected in virtual DOM then it compare's the actual DOM with virtual one and re-render the changes.